# Makefile, circular dependency dropped, clarification needed

Tags: c++, makefile, circular-dependency

In a makefile of

```
  1 SHELL=/bin/zsh
  2 CC=g++
  3 
  4 TARGET  = target/jj
  5 SOURCES = $(shell echo src/*.cpp)
  6 HEADERS = $(shell echo include/*.h)
  7 OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
  8 FLAGS   = -Wall -c
  9 
 10 all: $(TARGET)
 11 
 12 # Create final executable from .o
 13 $(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
 14   $(CC) $(OBJECTS)
 15 
 16 # Create .o from .cpp
 17 $(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)              # <------------------------------
 18   $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $(SOURCES)
 19 
 20 # Remove objects  
 21 clean:
 22   rm -rf $(OBJECTS)
```

So .. on line 17, `$(OBJECTS)` creation does depend on `$(SOURCES)` which are used in .o creation. Why does this line create a circular dependency? (Changing line to `$(TARGET):` instead, works fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on line 7—your source files are `.cpp` files but you are using the substitution `.c -> .o`. Try changing that to `.cpp`.